# How can I use strcmp on the return values of an exploded array

Tags: php, arrays, explode, strcmp

I am trying to factor common words out of a list. My common words were in a massive string separated by new lines. I put individual words into array elements by replacing the new lines with commas and then exploded the string with the comma as my delimiter.

```
common = preg_replace("/\n/", ",",$common);
$check = array();
$check = explode("," , $common);
```

However, when I try to check a word against this using strcmp, or by flipping the values with the keys using array flip and then using array_key_exists I get nothing even if I type the two strings to look identically the same. I believe this is because in the array the string is preceded by the word string? Not sure though, how can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe your newlines are "\r\n". try `$common=str_replace("\n",",",str_replace("\r","",$common));`

Comment: unfortunately it still does not recognize the two words

Comment: Put some sample data and sample results in the question for us to look at.  Also, you're missing a `$` on the first `$common` on the first line of code.